# How can I set the output value of a WMIC command to check the notebook battery as a batch variable?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I want to read out details about the battery as follows:

`WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining`

Can I then display the output of this using the `%value%` variable, for example?

Answer (score 1):

A batch file for this task is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "EstimatedChargeRemaining="
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_Battery GET EstimatedChargeRemaining /VALUE 2^>nul') do set "EstimatedChargeRemaining=%%I"
if defined EstimatedChargeRemaining echo Estimated remaining battery charge: %EstimatedChargeRemaining% %%
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic path /?`
- `wmic path win32_battery /?`
- `wmic path win32_battery get /?`

See also the Microsoft documentation page for the [Win32_Battery class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-battery).